# Bottom navigation не показывает View компоненты

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view, navigation

Я пытаюсь создать Bottom navigation с помощью Navigation Component, но столкнулся с одной проблемой: в моих фрагментах не отображаются элементы представления. Я думаю, это потому, что что-то пошло не так с моими стилями (в версии 4.1.2 у нас есть themes.xml и themes (night) .xml вместо styles.xml). И я поставил одинаковые стили для обоих файлов. Но когда я запускаю своё приложение на устройстве (с темным режимом), мои фрагменты не показывают элементы представления, после этого я попытался изменить режим (с темного на светлый) и увидел элементы представления (Менял тему через шторку). Но после этого я снова попытался изменить режим (обратно в темный режим) и увидел, что некоторые из моих элементов стали тусклыми. Это странно, потому что я использую одну и ту же тему и одинаковые цвета для обоих themes.xml. Еще одна вещь, после смены режима все работает, но после закрытия и перезапуска приложение больше не отображает элементы просмотра. Как это исправить?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment)
                as NavHostFragment

        binding.bottomNavigationView.apply {
            background = null
            menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false
            setupWithNavController(navHostFragment.findNavController())
            setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { Unit }
        }

        binding.fabNewPost.setOnClickListener {
            navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.globalActionToCratePostFragment
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.logout -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java).also {
                    startActivity(it)
                }
                finish()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

**themes.xml и themes.xml(night)**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TripApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/GreenButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="bottomAppBarStyle">@style/BottomAppBarStyle</item>
    <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/FloatingActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkBackground</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardViewStyle</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/TextInputLayoutStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="startIconTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@drawable/edit_text_box_border</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/mediumDarkBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
    <item name="background">@color/mediumDarkBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomAppBarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mediumDarkBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semibold</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="RedButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semibold</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="FloatingActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!--<item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/FabDiamondOverlay</item>-->
</style>

<style name="FabDiamondOverlay" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0%</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Скриншоты, код (не стили) и указание версии студии с вероятностью 99% - лишние в вопросе. А вот описание того как именно вы меняете тему с ночной на обратную в вопросе не видно.

Comment: Тему меняю через шторку, тестировал как на эмуляторе так и на физ. устройстве, результат одинаковый, причём до того как мы попадаем на активити с Bottom Navigation, фрагмент логина и регистрации отображается нормально и стили применяются к элементам корректно.